# How to add <! [CDATA[ tag to exist XML file

Tags: xml, vb.net

I want to add this  tag to my xml file using this code :

```
Dim FilePath As String
    FilePath = "C:\Users\MONZER\Desktop\Karary Web Site\WebApplication1\XMLFile1.xml"
    Dim document As New XDocument
    If File.Exists(FilePath) Then
        document = XDocument.Load(FilePath)
    Else
        Label1.Text = "not done"
    End If

    Dim root = New XElement("item")
    Dim title = New XElement("title", "<![CDATA[" & TextBox3.Text & "]]>")
    Dim link = New XElement("link", TextBox6.Text)
    root.Add(title, link)
    document.Root.Add(root)
    document.Save(FilePath)
    Label1.Text = "done"

End Sub
```

but it is not working, help me please !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
 Dim title = New XElement("title", New XCData(TextBox3.Text))
```

XCData is the LINQ to XML class that wraps CDATA chunks.

There is also an [alternative syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/xml/xml-literals-overview):

```
 Dim title = <title><%= New XCData(TextBox3.Text)) %></title>
```